# Does Jack die in the end of the movie Jack and the Cuckoo-Clock Heart?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, jack-and-the-cuckoo-clock-heart

I'd just like to know if Jack died in the end of [*Jack and the Cuckoo-Clock Heart*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1181840/). I mean, seriously, I need to know. They somewhat suggest it, sure, but I mean, he could be just dreaming or something... So does he die?

Comment: I found this and it makes sense! Such a loving story! https://m.fanfiction.net/s/10783416/1/Jack-and-the-Cuckoo-Clock-Heart-Epilogue :)

Comment: I thought Jack froze time.. that why his love was frozen or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Jack does die because He will only live as long as He observes three golden rules: 1 - He must never touch the hands of the clock. 2 - He must master his anger. 3 - He must never, ever fall in love. But fall in love Jack does, to a bespectacled young street performer, Miss Acacia, with a soul-stirring voice. And because of that last rule He does eventually die.

Answer (score 1):

According to the original story the movie is based on, *La Mécanique du Cœur*, he does not die, his clock heart actually has a real heart grow in its place but Madeline does not tell him the truth for fear of losing him.

I do think in the movie, we are supposed to think he has died. I believe he is "climbing into heaven" and leaving her behind. The pause in the film is his final memory as he leaves, which is why she doesn't move when time stops as she does in other parts of the movie, she has been left behind from this final fantasy.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the end of the song he is singing while he climbs. He says he is dead during the credits. I am pretty sure they put that in there to dispute any doubt that he died.

Answer (score 0):

I thought he lived because when they kissed his heart wound up without needing the key (plus someone mentioned here that he lived in the book). I saw everything standing still as "time standing still" because it was such a big moment for him. Not to mention he wasn't sad at all to be leaving her behind, which he would have been if he were dying. plus, the song he sings is about both of them climbing the sky together and stuff, as if they would be together for a long time. So I saw it as him living BECAUSE he kissed her and the kiss unexpectedly wound his heart up and saved his life.

Answer (score 0):

Jack dose not die, the movie ends when he falls unconscious and thus he believes he died due to what he was told, the last scene what his imagination of his death. If people believe in something strongly enough then it will effect the mind.
But yeah in the end His Heart was re-wounded back from the kiss and that then lead to Jacks Idea of his death as he fell Unconscious

Answer (score 0):

I think in the movie Jack dies and climbs to heaven but not necessarily dies from love. I think it was heartbreak from Miss Acacia rejecting him and finding out Madeline died, I know how it feels when a parent dies having lost my own mum, coupled with his clock simply winding down and him choosing not to let Acacia rewind it. Whether it was him deciding he was dieing anyway so he wanted her to kiss him before he did or whether the kiss did it I think is up to everyone's own interpretation of things much like how if you've read the book/seen the music videos you know he originally lives so you may think/decide that he simply passed out and imagined it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so Ive been pondering about the ending and I think I figured it out. So in the movie when Jack gives Miss Acacia his key they sang a little song and at the end he says lets make time stand still as he leans in to kiss her. So in the end when they kissed time froze because of the wonderfulness from the kiss and he started climbing because when he kissed her he felt brave as he told her when they had their little dispute and then the song at the end talks about them doing things together which means that hes still alive. Plus I believe that Jack is actually the narrator of his love story with her because in the beginning it was Jack's voice telling us of him being born with a frozen heart and that his mom climbed up to the house with a mid wife. So this proves that he is alive because, how can you tell a story about you if your dead.

Comment: *"how can you tell a story about you if your dead.*" - Because it's not real...

Answer (score -3):

He died. But not from love exactly.

Comment: Care to elaborate?